# How can I replace the general element of a geometric series with the sum of the series?

Tags: pattern-matching, list-manipulation

Consider the list

```
mylist = {b(a/bc t)^r, a/b(b t)^r, a (c/d t)^r, ...}
```

where a, b, c, t, etc., are real numbers between 0 and 1. I want to sum each term in the list over r from 1 to infinity. Since my list is very long, *Mathematica* takes a long time if I evaluate

```
Table[Sum[mylist[[k]], {r, 1, ∞}], {k, Length[mylist]}]
```

Instead, I would like to write a function which I can apply to the list such that for each element, `x^r -> x/(1-x)`? I think this would be a lot faster than *Mathematica* computing a geometric series for each element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
data = {b (a/bc t)^r, a/b (b t)^r, a (c/d t)^r};
sums = data /. Power[x_, r] -> x/(1 - x)
```

> $\left\{\frac{a b t}{\text{bc} \left(1-\frac{a t}{\text{bc}}\right)},\frac{a t}{1-b t},\frac{a c t}{d \left(1-\frac{c t}{d}\right)}\right\}$

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fairly general solution for the infinite sum of a real geometric term in an arbitrary variable `var` from `var = n0` to `Infinity`.  There may be some expressions involving special functions that can be simplified to a geometric term that `Simplify` might miss, and the use of `PowerExpand` may be omitted if `Complex` bases are to be used.  It was included here to handle `Sqrt` and other rational powers of expressions.  Whether or not to expand over `Plus` is left to the reader; omit the second part of the definition of `gsum` if it seems undesirable.

```
ClearAll[gsum];
SetAttributes[gsum, Listable];
Module[{r, n},
 gsum[term_, var_, n0_ : 0] /; FreeQ[r = Simplify[
                        PowerExpand[Divide @@ (term /. {{var -> n + 1}, {var -> n}})], 
                        n \[Element] Integers], n] :=
   With[{a = term /. var -> 0},  a/(1 - r)];
 gsum[t1_ + t2_, var_, , n0_ : 0] := gsum[t1, var, n0] + gsum[t2, var, n0];
 ]
```

The OP's examples:

```
terms = {b (a/bc t)^r, a/b (b t)^r, a (c/d t)^r};

gsum[terms, r, 1]

  (* {(a b t)/(bc (1 - (a t)/bc)), (a t)/(1 - b t), (a c t)/(d (1 - (c t)/d))} *)
```

Further examples.  The last contains terms that do not form geometric sums.  The expression `gsum` returns unevaluated (after threading over `Plus`).

```
gsum[{3^r (a + 2)^(2 r), a^(5 r + 3), a^r + b^r + c^r, Sqrt[a^r], r^2 + 2 b^r + c^r^2}, r]

  (* {1/(1 - 3 (2 + a)^2),   a^3/(1 - a^5),
      1/(1 - a) + 1/(1 - b) + 1/(1 - c), 
      1/(1 - Sqrt[a]),       2/(1 - b) + gsum[c^r^2, r] + gsum[r^2, r]} *)
```